# Take() takes different values than Skip() skips

Tags: c#, linq

I have written two different queries, the first one is supposed to get the first 5 objects, and then the next one is supposed to get the next 5 objects ordered by the purchased value. The problem is that the two values in the middle are the same and when I take the first five objects, and then skip the first five objects and take the next five objects the last object of the first set is the same as the first value of the second set and the object with the same purchased value as this object is never shown. My queries are below.

```
var query = (from v in db.VideoGames
             where v.gamesystem == "PC"
             orderby v.purchased descending
             select v).Take(5);

var query2 = (from v in db.VideoGames
             where v.gamesystem == "PC"
             orderby v.purchased descending
             select v).Skip(5).Take(5);
```

I would like to know if there is something that I can do differently to keep this from happening.

Edit: I feel that my explanation may be a little confusing so I am going to add an example given 10 VideoGame objects in a database and there purchased value.

- VideoGame1.purchased = 1,
- VideoGame2.purchased = 2,
- VideoGame3.purchased = 3,
- VideoGame4.purchased = 4,
- VideoGame5.purchased = 5,
- VideoGame6.purchased = 5,
- VideoGame7.purchased = 7,
- VideoGame8.purchased = 8,
- VideoGame9.purchased = 9,
- VideoGame10.purchased = 10

Here is what I am receiving

`query`: VideoGame10, VideoGame9, VideoGame8, VideoGame7, VideoGame5

`query2`: VideoGame5, VideoGame4, VideoGame3, VideoGame2, VideoGame1

Here is what I want

`query`: VideoGame10, VideoGame9, VideoGame8, VideoGame7, VideoGame6

`query2`: VideoGame5, VideoGame4, VideoGame3, VideoGame2, VideoGame1

I do not care if I get VideoGame5 in the first query, just as long as I get both the VideoGame5 object and the VideoGame6 object.

Comment: Your code is correct, it's probably a code 18. https://ideone.com/fF1GL4

Comment: @MatthewHaugen No it is not. The point of his question is when you have a item listed twice and you sort and page break on that duplicate in the sort how to make sure one item always stays on one side of the break and one item stays on the other side of the break.

Comment: Not a typo and Scott posted a solution to it.

Comment: Did you notice that `purchased = 5` appears twice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> the object with the same purchased value as this object is never shown

It did not click till I read this sentence a few times. Assuming you mean you have data like the following

```
class Videogames
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int purchased { get; set; }
    public string gamesystem { get; set; }

    public Videogames(string name, int purchased)
    {
        Name = name;
        this.purchased = purchased;
        gamesystem = "PC";
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var VideoGames = new List<Videogames>();
    VideoGames.Add(new Videogames("A", 1));
    VideoGames.Add(new Videogames("B", 2));
    VideoGames.Add(new Videogames("C", 2));
    VideoGames.Add(new Videogames("D", 3));

    var query = (from v in VideoGames
                 where v.gamesystem == "PC"
                 orderby v.purchased descending
                 select v).Take(2);

    var query2 = (from v in VideoGames
                  where v.gamesystem == "PC"
                  orderby v.purchased descending
                  select v).Skip(2).Take(2);
}
```

You are getting results like `A, B` and `B, D`...

The problem is you do not have deterministic sorting, when there is a tie it is up to whatever underlying system is performing the `orderby` (likely SQL server, and this is EF or Similar).

To fix this you must make your sorting system more specific so there is no ambiguous ties for the sorting engine to decide for you.

Changing your queires to

```
var query = (from v in VideoGames
             where v.gamesystem == "PC"
             orderby v.purchased descending, v.Name ascending 
             select v).Take(2);

var query2 = (from v in VideoGames
              where v.gamesystem == "PC"
              orderby v.purchased descending, v.Name ascending 
              select v).Skip(2).Take(2);
```

would fix it. You did not show your model so I had to make up a field `Name`. In database situations you usualy have some kind of primary key `ID` field, just make your queries sort by the primary key as the last sorting parameter and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You must have wrote this while I was writing my edit to try and explain the question better.